# EnableBluetooth() permission popup handle

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I had developed Bluetooth mobile application in react native. I want to access Bluetooth permission alert popup.

**Used package:**

```
npm i --save react-native-ble-manager
```

**Using function:**

```
BleManager.enableBluetooth()
```

If bluetooth **OFF** show bluetooth permission alert box while if touch outside the alert box was disappearing. How to fix this disappear problem.

[image]

Comment: what are you using to display this popup ?

Comment: @Jigar I do not show display popup .its appear from BleManager.enableBluetooth(). so I want how to handle this popup outside touch

Answer (score -1):

`enableBluetooth`

Create the request to the user to activate the bluetooth. Returns a Promise object.

Try this

```
BleManager.enableBluetooth()
.then(() => {
    // Success code
    console.log('The bluetooth is already enabled or the user confirm');
    this.setState({ isBluetooth: true })
    this.startConnect();
})
.catch((error) => {
    //Failure code
    Alert.alert('', 'Please turn on your bluetooth',
        [
            { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel' },
            {
                text: 'Settings', onPress: () => {
                    AndroidOpenSettings.bluetoothSettings()
                }
            },
        ])
    return;
});
```

**Reference**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-manager#enablebluetooth-android-only

I hope it help you

Comment: Would you please provide some more context to this code? What is startConnect()? Also, would be neat to include the imports so people can see that AndroidOpenSettings is as well.